# Django Unit Test: Exception on File Download

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, http, http-get

I'm using a Django Unit test to try and test a file download. It works as an API call, with a required token as a GET parameter, but nothing special. Code is:

```
from django.test.client import Client

c = Client()

base_url = str(sample_download_resource_uri) + '?token=' + str(account_token)
response = c.get(base_url)

if response.status_code != 200:
    return False, "Status code for /download_attachment/XYZ/ is not 200"
```

The URL is something like: `/download_attachment/1/` or `/download_attachment/2/`

Depending on the file ID.

When I try to run the unit test, in the line:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
```

I obtain the error: `I/O exception on closed file.`

I try the URL from the call in the browser and it works perfectly.

I'm not running the unit test through the tests.py file and tests command, instead using a Django view to remotely unit test the web server. But that shouldn't make a difference because all other non-download unit tests work, for both GET and POST commands.

Comment: What is the type of the variable `c`?

Comment: Sorry, Client() of the django.unit.test package. Edited.

Comment: Would help to include the full traceback so it's clear which line of code is generating the exception.

Comment: I understand. Will do.